# Save a custom class to Isolated Storage using a Collection

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, bitmapimage

I have created a custom class named `ImageItem` which contains a BitmapImage and string to gather the response of the `CaptureImageTask`. I would like to save each image and its respective path to an `ObservableCollection` which is bound to a listbox in my view.

As of now the listbox populates correctly, but **I am having trouble storing `ObservableCollection<ImageItem>` in isolated storage**, I believe because of the `BitmapImage type`.

I am not sure of how to fix my solution so that the `BitmapImage` will be allowed to be saved to isolated storage along with its respective path within an `ObservableCollection`.

I believe I have narrowed down the issue to `BitmapImage` not being a serializable type. I have tried using `[DataContract]` and '[DataMember]`attributes within`ImageItem.cs` without success. I have never attempted to save a nonprimitive type.

Following are the code, with some description of each file.

- ImageItem.cs

  ```
  public class ImageItem
  {
      public BitmapImage ImageUri
      {
          get;
          set;
      }

      public string ImagePath
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }
  ```
- Settings.cs

  I am using a `Settings` class to create the `ObservableCollection` of custom type.

  ```
  public static class Settings
  {
      public static readonly Setting<ObservableCollection<ImageItem>> imageList = new Setting<ObservableCollection<ImageItem>>("imageList", new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>());
  }
  ```
- Setting.cs

  Where `Setting` is a class that reads and saves data to Isolated Storage

  ```
  public class Setting<T>
  {
      string name;
      T value;
      T defaultValue;
      bool hasValue;

      public Setting(string name, T defaultValue)
      {
          this.name = name;
          this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
      }

      public T Value
      {
          get
          {
              //Check for the cached value
              if (!this.hasValue)
              {
                  //Try to get the value from Isolated Storage
                  if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(this.name, out this.value))
                  {
                      //It hasn't been set yet
                      this.value = this.defaultValue;
                      IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = this.value;
                  }
                  this.hasValue = true;
              }
              return this.value;
          }

          set
          {
              //Save the value to Isolated Storage
              IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = value;
              this.value = value;
              this.hasValue = true;
          }
      }

      public T DefaultValue
      {
          get { return this.defaultValue; }
      }

      // Clear cached value
      public void ForceRefresh()
      {
          this.hasValue = false;
      }
  }
  ```
- MainPage.xaml.cs

  From here I am simply attempting to save the result of the `CameraCaptureTask` which is used to populate the `ObservableCollection` and the listbox

  ```
  void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
  {
      if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
      {
          //values declared earlier
          imgChosenPhotoFilePath = null;
          bmp = new BitmapImage();

          imgChosenPhotoFilePath = e.OriginalFileName;

          bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
          imgChosenPhoto.Source = bmp;

          //Add photo to listbox and observablecollection
          AddToImgList(imgChosenPhotoFilePath, bmp);
      }
  }

  private void AddToImgList(string filePath, BitmapImage bitmap)
  {
      //save the values to the ObservableCollection
      Settings.imageList.Value.Add(new ImageItem() { ImagePath = filePath, ImageUri = bitmap });

      //populate the listbox in the view named imgList
      imgList.ItemsSource = Settings.imageList.Value;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you can't serialize the `BitmapImage`. The simplest alternative would be to save this as a separate file and then save the name of the file in the collection you're serializing.

Obviously, when deserializing, you'll need to read the file from disk and load it back into a BitmapImage.

If you're persisting this data for use across the lifetime of the app it'll probably be easier to just save the images straight to IsolatedStorage and keep the paths in your view model. You can then bind the path to an Image in the ListBoxItemTemplate.

Comment: Most of the data will be persisted across the lifetime of the app. I understand how to save images individually to IsolatedStorage, but I was placing them in an ObservableCollection so the user may quickly add or delete images and this would automatically be managed. Also, there may be hundreds of images collected, so I assumed this was the best approach but it is becoming more difficult than I anticipated. Might you show me an example of what you mean by saving the images individually in IsolatedStorage and then binding the paths to the ListBoxItemTemplate? And is this more efficient?